# How to select count(*) from many to many in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables (for example posts:tags) with M:N relationship with standard middle table.
I want to select all post ids with the count of tags per each post with spring data jpa.

Here is what i did:

`SELECT p.id, count(t) as total FROM post p join p.tags t;`

However this is not returning the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it, adding group by did the trick.

```
SELECT p.id, count(t) as total 
FROM post p join p.tags t 
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: This answer is not very helpfull, but it would become more helpfull when you post the "trick" by example.